# Can't fix code for sorting only used cells in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have an incomplete table with a  lot of empty cells right now:
Header line Row 3
Data Cells A4:H13
As yet empty Cells which will be needed later A14:H38

I am trying to create a macro to auto-sort the data based on Column B which is numerical (since I can't seem to record a macro automatically which lets me sort 'Largest to Smallest'??). So far I have the following:

```
Sub sortonmcols()
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A4:H" & lastRow).Select.CurrentRegion.Sort _
key1:=Range("B3"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
key2:=Range("A3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

I had the simple sortonmcols working but it put all the empty cells to the top, so I found the lastRow code and added that in, and now when running it I get the Runtime Error 424: Object Required error. I'm not clear why, as I haven't changed the final two rows!

Any help much appreciated!

P.S. EDIT: An edit to the above, which I hadn't thought of: only Columns A and B are guaranteed to have content in for all the rows of data. Cols C-H have VLOOKUP formulae for all 34 rows already, but may not be showing any results for any given row.

Comment: Lose the `.Select` and  probably also the `.CurrentRegion`

Comment: @TimWilliams worked first time. Thank you so much!!